# How to find the basis containing eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For example. There is a linear operator on 3-dimensional complex vector space $T: V\rightarrow V$. Then, there are two eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$. Then, because the vector space has dimension 3, its basis should be something like $(e_1,e_2,e_3)$. If I let two eigenvectors with different eigenvalues become basis vectors in the basis, the basis will be $(v_1,v_2,w_3)$. And the matrix under this new basis should be like

$\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1&0&*\ \\0&\lambda_2&* \\0&0&* \end{bmatrix}$

Then, how can I find the last vector $w_3$ in the basis and fill the "*" part of this matrix?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have a go at the Jordan basis

Comment: Ok, I have not learned this part yet. If solving this question needs this part of knowledge, I'll go to read my book. Thanks

Comment: Well the Jordan basis is simply the nicer way to do it. You could in fact choose any old vector $w_3$ that is linearly independent of $v_1,v_2$, and then you must fill the final column with the image $T(w_3)$

Comment: The Jordan basis is nicer in that all the diagonal entries are eigenvalues + it always exists uniquely. Finding it can be a bit of a chore however!